# How can I set title of NavifationItem from IB (separate xib of my own ViewController)

Tags: iphone, title, xib, navigationitem

Can anybody help me in such situation:
I have Navigation interface in my application and push TestController to nav stack

Also I have separate xib file: Test.xib where File owner's is TestController. Test.xib has View (property TopBar set as NavigationBar and it shows) with only TextView.

All works fine: Controller is pushed to stack, Back button is shown but there is no Title of TestController and I can't drop NavigationItem on the View to display own title.

How can I set in Test.xib Title on the NavigationBar ???

PS: Programmatically works (in TestController.m -> ViewDidLoad: self.title=@"Test controller";) but I need exactly in xib from IB (it's requirement of my employer)

Regards, Alex

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UINavigationItem` and set the properties there.

Comment: Tried before had written - did not added. I see NavigationItem in the list of objects of xib but no this item on the windows shows UI. Trying drag'n'drop from Library to window with UI get bounce back.

Comment: Not sure it is possible then - out of interest, why exactly do you need to do this? I cannot see any practical purpose

Comment: Thanks for answer.
>why exactly do you need to do this? I cannot see any practical purpose

Me too, but as I wrote my employer require it from me